# Could not find jaxws frontend within classpath

Tags: java, wsdl

Im trying to use wsdl2java tool same error every time. Any ideas much appreciated
-fe jaxbs didn't help. Looks like it failes to find tools-plugin.xml.

```
15:18:37.618 [main] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.PluginLoader - Found 4 databindings in <source> plugin.
15:18:37.618 [main] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.PluginLoader - Loading <source> databinding from <source> plugin.
15:18:37.619 [main] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.PluginLoader - Loading <domsource> databinding from <source> plugin.
15:18:37.619 [main] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.PluginLoader - Loading <staxsource> databinding from <source> plugin.
15:18:37.620 [main] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.PluginLoader - Loading <saxsource> databinding from <source> plugin.
15:18:37.623 [main] ERROR com.smalik.wsdl2yamlspec.WsdlToYamlSpec - Something went wrong
org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ToolException: Could not find jaxws frontend within classpath
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.PluginLoader.getFrontEnd(PluginLoader.java:254)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.PluginLoader.getFrontEndProfile(PluginLoader.java:389)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.loadFrontEnd(WSDLToJava.java:64)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:96)
        at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:86)
        at com.smalik.wsdl2yamlspec.WsdlToYamlSpec.getGeneratedClassLoader(WsdlToYamlSpec.java:84)
        at com.smalik.wsdl2yamlspec.WsdlToYamlSpec.convert(WsdlToYamlSpec.java:53)
        at com.smalik.wsdl2yamlspec.WsdlToYamlSpec.main(WsdlToYamlSpec.java:46)
```

java version "1.8.0_231"

Answer (score -1):

Found out how to resolve this issue run

```
sudo java -cp "wsdl-to-yaml-0.0.1.jar:lib/*" com.smalik.wsdl2yamlspec.WsdlToYamlSpec
```

added following jar to /lib

```
cxf-rt-wsdl-3.1.9.jar
cxf-tools-wsdlto-databinding-jaxb-3.1.9.jar
cxf-tools-wsdlto-frontend-jaxws-3.1.9.jar
```